# I'm running to run my api on a live server

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, multer

I built an api on my local server that allows people to send messages and media files to multiple people on their whatsapp. all you have to do was to present the numbers in a csv file. as I ran it in my local server it was working but as I tried to my it live and host it on live server like render.com, the chromium browser and the enry code started have issues as if their was no code written.

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { error } = require('console');
const { Session } = require('inspector');
const { MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { forEach } = require('lodash');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors())
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null,'Csv/');
    },
    filename:(req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  });

  const Csv = multer({
    storage: storage
  })



  const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, './uploads'); // The directory where uploaded files will be saved
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname); // Use the original file name
    },
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage: Storage });

// Initialize the WhatsApp client



app.get('/send', (req, res) => {
    const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    // Options for the client
      puppeteer: {
          headless: false,
          args:[
              '--no-sandbox',
              '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
              ]
              }
  });
  
  client.on('qr', (qr) => {
   // Generate and display the QR code in the terminal
   console.log('QR Code:', qr);
  });
  
  client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('Client is ready!');
  });
  
  client.initialize();
})


app.post('/send-message', Csv.single('numbers'), async (req, res) => {
  
    try {
      const message = req.body.message;
        const numbers = await promisify(fs.readFile)(req.file.path);
        console.log(message);
        console.log(numbers);
        let number = numbers.toString().split('\r\n');
        for (let index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
          let test = number[index]
          console.log(test);
          let code = await client.sendMessage('234' + test + '@c.us', message);
          console.log(code);
        }
    
        // Send the message to each number
    //         console.log('Message sent to:', number);
    //         
    
        res.status(200).send('Messages sent successfully!');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
         res.status(500).send('Failed to send messages!');
      }
});


app.post('/send-media', upload.fields([{ name: 'media', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'csv', maxCount: 1 }]), async(req, res) => {
  const csvFile = await promisify(fs.readFile)(req.files['csv'][0].path);
  const mediaFile = req.files['media'][0];
  const message = req.body.message;
  console.log(mediaFile);
  console.log(message);
  try{

  let number = csvFile.toString().split('\r\n');
  console.log(number);
  for (let index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
    let csv = number[index]
      const chat = await client.getChatById('234' + csv + '@c.us');
      console.log(chat);
      const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath(mediaFile.path);
      chat.sendMessage(media, { caption: message });
  };
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Media sent' })
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to send media' });
}
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

I tired to edit it on github and I made some changes to it

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { error } = require('console');
const { Session } = require('inspector');
const { MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const { forEach } = require('lodash');
const cors = require('cors');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors())
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null,'Csv/');
    },
    filename:(req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  });

  const Csv = multer({
    storage: storage
  })



  const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, './uploads'); // The directory where uploaded files will be saved
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname); // Use the original file name
    },
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage: Storage });

// Initialize the WhatsApp client



const client = new Client({
  puppeteer: {
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
    ],
  } 
  // Options for the client
});

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
 // Generate and display the QR code in the terminal
 console.log('QR Code:', qr);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();


app.post('/send-message', Csv.single('numbers'), async (req, res) => {
  
    try {
      const message = req.body.message;
        const numbers = await promisify(fs.readFile)(req.file.path);
        console.log(message);
        console.log(numbers);
        let number = numbers.toString().split('\r\n');
        for (let index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
          let test = number[index]
          console.log(test);
          let code = await client.sendMessage('234' + test + '@c.us', message);
          console.log(code);
        }
    
        // Send the message to each number
    //         console.log('Message sent to:', number);
    //         
    
        res.status(200).send('Messages sent successfully!');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
         res.status(500).send('Failed to send messages!');
      }
});


app.post('/send-media', upload.fields([{ name: 'media', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'csv', maxCount: 1 }]), async(req, res) => {
  const csvFile = await promisify(fs.readFile)(req.files['csv'][0].path);
  const mediaFile = req.files['media'][0];
  const message = req.body.message;
  console.log(mediaFile);
  console.log(message);
  try{

  let number = csvFile.toString().split('\r\n');
  console.log(number);
  for (let index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
    let csv = number[index]
      const chat = await client.getChatById('234' + csv + '@c.us');
      console.log(chat);
      const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath(mediaFile.path);
      chat.sendMessage(media, { caption: message });
  };
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Media sent' })
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Failed to send media' });
}
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

it is meant to send whatsapp message and media file to multiple on whatsapp at the same time